# Creating new TextView isn't working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I have a Spinner, EditText and a Button. When I enter something in EditText and then click on a Button, I want it to create a new TextView according to which item on spinner is selected.

Button click method:

```
public void submitScore(View v){
    final int position = playerList.getSelectedItemPosition();
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    createNewTextView (players.get(position) + input);
}
```

createNewTextView():

```
private TextView createNewTextView (String text){
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);

    newTextView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    newTextView.setText(text);
    return newTextView;
}
```

Whole XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Igra" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Enter"
    android:onClick="submitScore" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Score:" />
```

As you can see; I have both Relative and Linear Layout inside this activity and they are separated (LinearLayout is under the RelativeLayout).

I want this TextView to be added into LinearLayout but it isn't added anywhere, I can't see it when I press a button.

My code now:

```
public void submitScore(View v){
    LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.linearLayout);
    final int position = playerList.getSelectedItemPosition();
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
    newTextView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    newTextView.setText(players.get(position) + input);

    //createNewTextView (players.get(position) + input);
    lLayout.addView(newTextView);
}
```

Result: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see any textView that you have created because you didn't add any of them to your layout. (As far as I see from information yo gave)

Give an id to your linearLayout and in your submitScore() method get your layout by id then add your editText to your layout that you've created by createNewTextView() method.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/myTextViewContainer"
...
>
</LinearLayout>


public void submitScore(View v){
   ....
   TextView newTextView = createNewTextView (players.get(position) + input);
   LinearLayout myTextViewContainer=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTextViewContainer);
   myTextViewContainer.addView(newTextView);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I did exactly this (check my edited post to see new code and screenshot). The textview is added now but it is not what I want it to be. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I accidently removed my answer sorry:) I think using "final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);" solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

On `submitScore()` you are creating a `TextView` but isn't adding it to the `LinearLayout`.

Give you `LinearLayout` an `android:id` value then, on `submitScore()`, get its reference and call the `add()` method of the `LinearLayout` to add the value returned from `createNewTextView ()`

Comment: I did this, please check my added code and my screenshot. The textview is added now but it is not what I want it to be. Any idea what's wrong? thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Matthew Shouldn't you call `newTextView.setText(players.get(position) + input.getText());`?

Also, if you add a lot of `View`s in your `LinearLayout`, when it's full, the new `View`s won't appear. You may need a `ScrollView`

Comment: Thank you for reminfing me about the getText(), totally forgot about that. I already added scrollview, right after opening this question :) thank you for your answer, but I have accepted another one since he gave me the final solution, but I will upvote yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a textview from xml and make it invisible

```
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

then when you select something it becomes visible with the text wanted ..

```
private TextView createNewTextView (String text){
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textview.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Because I don't know how many textviews the user will add. The number is not limited.

Comment: oh x.x sorry I didn't know that